# Using malloc instead of new, and calling the copy constructor when the object is created

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, new-operator, tbb

I wanted to try out TBB's scalable_allocator, but was confused when I had to replace some of my code.
This is how allocation is done with the allocator:

```
SomeClass* s = scalable_allocator<SomeClass>().allocate( sizeof(SomeClass) );
```

**EDIT: What's shown above is not how allocation is done with scalable_allocator. As [ymett correctly mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956249/using-malloc-instead-of-new-and-calling-the-copy-constructor-when-the-object-is/4958301#4958301), allocation is done like this:**

```
int numberOfObjectsToAllocateFor = 1;
SomeClass* s = scalable_allocator<SomeClass>().allocate( numberOfObjectsToAllocateFor );
scalable_allocator<SomeClass>().construct( s, SomeClass());
scalable_allocator<SomeClass>().destroy(s);
scalable_allocator<SomeClass>().deallocate(s, numberOfObjectsToAllocateFor);
```

It's pretty much like using a malloc:

```
SomeClass* s = (SomeClass*) malloc (sizeof(SomeClass));
```

This is the code I wanted to replace:

```
SomeClass* SomeClass::Clone() const
{
   return new SomeClass(*this);
}//Clone
```

So tried a program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class S
{
        public:
        int i;
        S() {cout<<"constructed"<<endl;}
        ~S() {cout<<"destructed"<<endl;}
        S(const S& s):i(s.i) {}
};

int main()
{
        S* s = (S*) malloc(sizeof(S));
        s = (S*) S();//this is obviously wrong
        free(s);
}
```

and here I found that calling malloc does not instantiate the object (I've never used malloc earlier). So before figuring out how to pass `*this` to the copy ctor, I'd like to know how to instantiate the object when working with malloc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new

Comment: Why won't you override `operator new` either for the class you're interested in or just the global one?

Comment: @sharptooth: That's a nice idea, but for now, I'm just testing to see if scalable_allocator really helps in avoiding heap contention. Overriding new will definitely come handy if the tests are successful. Thanks :)

Comment: If the allocator is standard-compliant, it should have the construct and destroy method: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/allocator/construct/

Comment: Overriding `operator new()` is much faster and more reliable - you just do that and recompile and see if it helps, you don't need to change the calling code - it will come into effect everywhere immediately.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You'll need to use `placement new` after getting the raw memory from `malloc`.

```
void* mem = malloc(sizeof(S));
S* s = new (mem) S(); //this is the so called "placement new"
```

When you're done with the object you have to make sure to explicitly call its destructor.

```
s->~S();
free(mem);
```

Comment: Thanks. It seemed counterintuitive to use 'new' when the whole purpose of using TBB's scalable_allocator was to replace new. But I guess it's different because it's placement new that's being used.

Answer (score 9):

Use [placement new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new)

```
#include <memory>
//...
int main()
{
        S* s = (S*) malloc(sizeof(S));
        s = new (s) S();//placement new
        //...
        s->~S();
        free(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to `allocate()` is the number of objects, not the size in bytes.
You then call the allocator's `construct()` function to construct the object.

```
scalable_allocator<SomeClass> sa;
SomeClass* s = sa.allocate(1);
sa.construct(s, SomeClass());
// ...
sa.destroy(s);
sa.deallocate(s);
```

If want to use it with a standard library container or other std allocator aware type, simply give it the allocator type.

```
std::vector<SomeClass, scalable_allocator<SomeClass>> v;
```

Comment: I disagree. construct() is used for the placement new functionality. I had taken the syntax of allocate() from one of the examples supplied in TBB. But since you posted this, I'm intrigued. I'll check and get back to you. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh my! You're right! Thank's a zillion for correcting me! It's sad this website does not have the option of voting up an answer more than once. I'd have voted it up a hundred times! One question: In the line sa.construct(s, SomeClass());
, is a temporary object of SomeClass() getting created? Also, I don't get the point of allocating for n objects. If I had done sa.allocate(2); then would I have to construct two objects using sa.construct(s, SomeClass()); ?      p.s: could you edit your answer a bit? SO isn't allowing me to vote up your answer saying that you need to edit it.

Comment: Edited my question to include a corrected version of the code. Thank you so much! The output to my program is now `constructed
destructed
destructed`. The first 'destructed' happens immediately after/during the construct() function. Wonder why.