# Pass a shared pointer out of C++ / Put a shared pointer on the heap

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to pass a shared pointer into Obj-C via void* so it can keep a particular object and then delete it (via C++ function).

Does this work?

I'm fine for a better idea, but this seems like the fastest way to get a reference to a shared pointer. Just want to make sure my math isn't off on the malloc (as I don't often use it).

```
std::shared_ptr<AAA> shared_ptr = getSharedPointer();
std::shared_ptr<AAA>* ptr = malloc(sizeof(std::shared_ptr<AAA>));
*ptr = shared_ptr;
return ptr;
```

Comment: malloc with a shared ptr? Don't ever do that.

Comment: How will Obj-C delete said pointer?  Use it?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do but it doesn't seem right.

Comment: It may be that Obj-C provides functionality that can make this easier, but the general solution is to give the other language an object pointer plus getref, addref and removeref functions. You **don't** give it a pointer to the implementation details of a C++ shared_ptr

Comment: Never used `Obj-C` but I would imagine the only thing you could pass to it would be the *raw pointer* obtained through `shared_ptr.get()`.

Comment: @Galik It would not be possible to use the shared pointer in Obj-C, only to hold on to it and pass it back to C++ to be deleted. This is possible via "pointer to void" void*. As to passing a reference to a shared ref, this is possible only if the object is moved to the heap, and understood that the ref-count does not change when the pointer ref is copied, but stays at 1.

Comment: Here is not a bad alternative (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482806/manually-incrementing-and-decrementing-a-boostshared-ptr), but I like this method much better.

Comment: @drescherjm: Actually, `shared_ptr` _can_ work with `malloc`, the bug is forgetting the customer deleter which calls `free`.

Answer (score 0):

Found via a search for malloc and c++ ([Using malloc instead of new, and calling the copy constructor when the object is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956249/using-malloc-instead-of-new-and-calling-the-copy-constructor-when-the-object-is))

Assignment works correctly as in the code in the OP, but it is then required to call the destructor manually and free() instead of delete.

I have tested with simple unit test that this works and the pointer reference counts are correctly incremented and decremented.